# How do I have the contacts name only once a text comes?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, sms, samsung

on my samsung android 4.3 I turned off in messages settings preview, now when I receive a text I get "new text messages". When turned on I get the contacts name & some of the text written from the person. Is there a way I can receive the contacts name only?

Comment: I don't think so, from what I can see on my S4 it's either 'New Text Message' or 'Name and Preview'. You could try a third party SMS application to see if this feature is present.